Adobe sign Recipients with duplicate emails and no signing order
I have a scenario where the a pdf document is generated dynamically and sending it for signature. I am placing text tags in the pdf document as below
PersonId       Name    Signature                                          Date
P1             ABC    {{Sig1_es_:signer1:signature}}         {{Dte1_es_:signer1:date}}
P2             XYZ    {{Sig2_es_:signer2:signature}}         {{Dte2_es_:signer2:date}}
Before sending it for signature, I save the recipient information to a table. In this case, P1 and P2 have the same email address, and both have a signing order of 1. P1 is the child, and P2 is the mother. How can I update the database table when a user signs or rejects?
The webhook response includes the following details:
{
"participantUserId": "CBJCHBCAABAApOhpy5n-9OG4zIUGhW-2l9dAtXFGnv0-",
"participantUserEmail": "mailid@gmail.com"
}
These details pertain to the user who signed or rejected.
Currently, after creating an agreement, I call this API to get the member list:
https://secure.in1.adobesign.com/api/rest/v6/agreements/CBJCHBCAABAAAVfVGu9kybbMbt_0tUUNMiFRiDBt4Fyi...
I update the database table to save the userId from the API response according to the order in which I sent member information during the agreement creation.
When I receive the webhook response, I use the participantUserId to update the status in the database.
However, if Adobe changes the order in which it returns the members, how can I handle this scenario?
Is it possible to pass a unique identifier for each member while creating an agreement and then retrieve that identifier in the webhook response to uniquely identify the user who signed or rejected?
